# django localflavors US

Tags: django, django-templates

The following shows up instead of a field in my template.

```
<django.contrib.localflavor.us.forms.USStateSelect object at 0x92b136c>
```

my template has

```
{{ form.state }}
```

what could the issue be?

```
class RegistrationForm(forms.Form):

    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=20)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=20)
    phone = USPhoneNumberField()
    address1 = forms.CharField(max_length=45)
    address2 = forms.CharField(max_length=45)
    city = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    state = USStateSelect()
    zip = USZipCodeField()
```

also is there anyway i can make the state and zip optional?

Comment: Could you post the code for your form class?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To limit the choices to a drop down list, use `us.us_states.STATE_CHOICES` in your model, and use `us.forms.USStateField()` instead of `us.forms.USStateSelect()` in your forms.

To make a field optional in a form, add `blank = True` to that field in the model.

```
from django.contrib.localflavor.us.us_states import STATE_CHOICES
from django.contrib.localflavor.us.models import USStateField

class ExampleLocation(models.Model):
    address1 = models.CharField(max_length=45) #this is not optional in a form
    address2 = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank = True) #this is made optional 
    state = USStateField(choices = STATE_CHOICES)
```

Instead of `STATE_CHOICES`, there are several options you can find [in the `localflavor` documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/localflavor/#django.contrib.localflavor.us.us_states.CONTIGUOUS_STATES). `STATE_CHOICES` is the most inclusive, but that may not be what you desire. If you just want 50 states, plus DC, use `US_STATES`.

---

This answer assumes you're using [ModelForms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/). If you aren't, you should be. Once you've made your model, you should follow DRY and create basic forms like so:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm

class ExampleForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ExampleLocation
```

And it inherits your fields from your model. You can customize what fields are available, if you don't want the whole model, with other `class Meta` options like `fields` or `exclude`. Model forms are just as customizable as any other form, they just start with the assumption of your model's fields.

Comment: Are you making the USStateField optional in the *model*, or the *form*? If this is just in a form, and it isn't associated with a model, use `required = False` in the form, instead of `blank = True`. Keep in mind, if you don't have `blank = True` in the model, and you attempt to add a new entry without that field, you'll receive an error.

Comment: Why is it called USStateSelect if it doesn't render a drop down select of US State choices?  Or am I missing something.